# Searching with bfs

Tags: java, hashset, wordnet, breadth-first-search

i have retrieve synsets from wordnet an return it as an array. This is part of my code

```
<pre>
RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
String word = lineTF.getText();
// Get synsets
String[] synsets = wordnet.getAllSynsets(word, "n");
String outputSynset = "Word: " + word;

    GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");
    GUIsynonymTA.append(outputSynset);
    GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");

    if (synsets != null) 
    {

    for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++) 
    {
    GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");
    GUIsynonymTA.append("Synsets " + i + ": " + (synsets[i]));                        
    GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");

    //implement BFS here
<code>
```

until this line, i have retrieved the synsets successfully. What i'm going to do is to implement the Breadth First Search in searching WordNet synsets. I'm calling the method getAllSynsets from RiWordnet library which stores all synonym in wordnet. I try using looping (if..else), but i'm not sure where to stop my search. Using BFS is expected to know the scope of the search, where the search synonym be marked as the nodes that were visited. Here is a concept that i would like to implement using BFS in searching synonym.

For example:

```
student = {pupil, educatee, scholar, bookman} 

pupil = {student, educatee, schoolchild}

educatee = {student, pupil} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

schoolchild = {pupil} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

scholar = {bookman, student, learner, assimilator}

bookman = {scholar, student} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

learner = {scholar, assimilator, apprentice, prentice}

assimilator = {learner, scholar} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

apprentice = {learner} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

prentice = {apprentice, learner} --> has been search, so go to the next synonym.

ALL SYNONYM HAS BEEN SEARCH, SO STOP.
```

Some people also suggested me to apply HashSet instead of BFS. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by BFS over synsets? They are plain data, and BFS is an algo for searching in graphs.

Comment: Got your idea from another your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935916/nested-search-of-synsets-from-wordnet-using-java), but what are you trying to find with BFS? If you just want to enumerate all synonyms and synonyms of synonyms, and synonyms of synonyms of synonyms etc., then use recursion and put all synonyms into HashSet to avoid circles.

Comment: thank you..actually BFS use the concept of visited and unvisited graph. i want to implement this to set the limit of searching. If the synonym is being search (it will be marked as visited in BFS), the search will stop. And the system will list down all synonym that has been found through the searching.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
Queue<String> pending = ...
HashSet<String> processed = ...

pending.add("startWord"); 
processed.add("startWord");

while (!pending.isEmpty()) {
   String word = pending.remove();

   String[] possibilities = wordnet.getAllSynsets(word, "n");
   for (String p : possibilities) {
     // Make sure we haven't already processed the new word 
     if (!processed.contains(p)) {
        pending.add(p);
        processed.contains(p);
      }
   }
}

//  At this point, processed contains all synonyms found
```

It's more or less a recursive expansion of the synonyms (which is basically what BFS is).